# Is it possible to change values in resource (.resx) file?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, resources

I have a SharePoint 2010 project with a feature. This feature will create an SPList on activation if it doesn't exist yet. When creating an SPList, the Add() method returns a Guid. I want to store this Guid in the resources file but I haven't found a way to do this. I know how to fetch items from the resources file but not how to update values. Is there a way to do this or not? If not, then what is the best approach to store values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As moontear wrote below property bag is useful and you can use p&p guidance library to work with it. But if you later need to interact with list by saved guid it's not good as someone could delete list. Instead you can search list by TemplateFeatureId http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.templatefeatureid.aspx if list is based on custom definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a resource file to store configuration values - a resource file's intend is for localizing strings.

You should use either one of these:

- SharePoint Property Bags, e.g. `ListItem.Properties` or `SPWeb.AllProperties`
- A hidden SharePoint "configuration list"
- The `web.config` to store your `AppSettings`

In your case you want to store the list GUID somewhere I would suggest storing it in the `SPWeb` property bag and you can later retrieve it by using `SPWeb.AllProperties['MyCustomListGUID']`

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, I will make use of the Property Bags! ;)